# Connection Not Established Ruby Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, rails-postgresql, pg

I am getting this error.

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
/Users/jod/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@BankingApp/gems/activerecord-    4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:546:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/jod/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@BankingApp/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:79:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/jod/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@BankingApp/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `connection'
/Users/jod/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@BankingApp/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:208:in `columns'
```

When trying to run a rake task. In the rake task it takes Class2 and does a create. This will try to create a record in the database.

I could understand this problem but Class1 is saving to the database and is working fine. IE if I save a user, it works as expected and if I save a car, it fails. The classes are identical.

I am using ruby on rails and postgres

Comment: I can save the model through active record. Its just when it is called through a rake task that it fails.

Comment: SOLUTION: I needed to set the environment to   task :import => :environment do That way it can see the DB

Answer (score 1):

When I first got Rails 4 set up, I only needed to set up the gem file to use `pg` and set up the `database.yml` file in the config folder to point to the appropriate database and supply it some credentials.

I would assume the task you mentioned in your comments is something that a previous version of Rails did not provide out of the box?